# How to setting a Class in a conditional statement of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

How to setting a Class in Javascript?
I going to use Addthis sharing buttons in my website. The problem is that I need to have two different Styles of Sharing buttons in to my website, one to be shown in a computer browser and other for a mobile device.

I'm going to use the below script. My question is how to include the code lines of two Styles sharing codes in the conditions of the javascript code? How to put the classes into the javascript condition because the sharing codes have Classes of CSS.

```
    <script >
    function detectmob() { 
     if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
     || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
     || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
     || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
     || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
     || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
     || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
     ){
        return true;  // Style for mobile devices
      }

     else {
        return false;  // Style for computer devices
      }
    }

//Style for mobile devices
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5149fd2b33068839"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->

// Style for Computer
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_floating_style addthis_32x32_style" style="left:50px;top:50px;">
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5149fd2b33068839"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: @gaynorvader: OP does not use jQuery

Comment: May as well start though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`className` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className) of the `<div>` element:

```
<div id="addthis-box" class="addthis_toolbox addthis_32x32_style">
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<script>
    var box = document.getElementById("addthis-box");
    if (detectmob()) {
        box.className += " addthis_default_style";
    } else {
        box.className += " addthis_floating_style";
        box.style.left = "50px";
        box.style.top = "50px";
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5149fd2b33068839"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Bergi. But is appearing a mix of both sharing buttons in both environments (mobile and computer). The conditional is taking all the statements of the class. Please look the page: http://www.expo-estudiante.com/colombia/index2.asp

Answer (score 2):

you can use `classList` instead of `className`. Your code should be something like:

```js
(function addConditionalStyles () {
  const desiredElement = document.querySelector('#desiredElement');

  desiredElement.classList.toggle('mobile-only-class', detectMobile());
})();
```

in this example, the class `.mobile-only-class` will be applied only if the function `detectMobile` evaluates to truthy value.

Comment: Great and very concise.

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to add a CSS Class dynamically, you can use

```
document.getElementById('the-element-s-id').className += 'the-desired-class';
```

If you want to only add the two (`left` and `top`), you can also use

```
e = document.getElementById('here-goes-the-element-s-id');
e.style.left = '50px';
e.style.top = '50px';
```

Although, I believe your technique is faulty as you're only targeting specific users, I advice you to have a look at CSS Media Queries and set your styles more generally.